# Drawing text on images in pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

i was trying to solve a problem i had in a code that should draw text from a text file on a picture. the problem i had is that the program stack all the text on each other in every picture after the first picture(2,3,4,5). i can't explain what's the problem so i'll just leave a photo (https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkY2O.png)

```
#vars
f = open("text.txt","r")
img = Image.open("testpic.jpg")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
img_center = (215,190)
fnt = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf',32)

#code
for i in range(1,6):
    img_txt = (f.readline())
    draw.text(img_center, img_txt, font=fnt, stroke_fill=(0, 0, 0))
    img.save('Image'+str(i)+'.png')
```

i tried to change the image text to f.readlines() but the problem was still there.

**The problem was solved a while ago but idk how to close the question, It was solved by adding i=+1 in the end of the code.**

Comment: I can't see what the problem, or actual question is. Do you mean the texts come out on top of each other because you draw them all in the same place?

Comment: yep the text come on top of each other. but i don't want that to happen i want every line in the text file to be in a single image

Comment: What's in the text.txt file?

Comment: Because you're drawing on the same image again and again and again. Every `draw.text` draws on top of the already modified image. If you don't want this to happen, then on every loop, you have to reread the unmodified source image. And instantiate a new ImageDraw as well.

Comment: Also, please use context managers when opening files... And rather than using `.readline()`, simply iterate on the opened file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty reasonable, but none too complicated method:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

# Generate annotations file with 3 lines
annotations = 'annotations.txt'
with open(annotations, 'w') as f:
    f.write("Merry\nChristmas\nStackOverflow")

# Open background and get dimensions
im = Image.open("background.jpg")
width, height = im.size

# Make a canvas to draw on, same size as background
# Set up everything necessary outside loop
canvas = im.copy()
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(canvas)
textpos = (int(width/4), int(height/3))
font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf',32)

# Iterate over lines in "annotations.txt"
N = 0
with open(annotations,"r") as f:
   while True:
      text = f.readline()
      if not text:
         break
      # Copy background onto our canvas - thereby clearing previous iteration
      canvas.paste(im)
      draw.text(textpos, text, font=font, stroke_fill=(0, 0, 0))
      canvas.save(f'image-{N}.png')
      N += 1
```

It produces three images:

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  2863 29 Nov 16:13 image-0.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  4134 29 Nov 16:13 image-1.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  5816 29 Nov 16:13 image-2.png
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's my modified version of your code:

```py
#vars
img = Image.open("testpic.jpg")
img_center = (215,190)
fnt = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf',32)

#code
with open("text.txt", "rt") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
        img_copy = img.copy()
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img_copy)
        draw.text(img_center, line, font=fnt, stroke_fill=(0, 0, 0))
        img_copy.save(f'Image{i}.png')
        if i == 6:
            break
```